# Imagem sobrepor LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, layout

Estou criando um layout e preciso que a imagem sobreponha parte do LinearLayout que faz o fundo da imagem.

Com o que eu tenho consegui fazer isso.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bgprofile"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_back"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_filtered_communities_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top|center"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="Perfil"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPicProfile"
            :layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O resultado é para ser algo do tipo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma seria botar uma marginTop de metade da foto, negativa, no Relative Layout dela, assim:

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="-55dp">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPicProfile"
        :layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        tools:src="@tools:sample/avatars" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Mas tem outras formas, como por exemplo, trocando o LinearLayout por LayoutConstraint.

Comment: irei ver se alguma das duas ideias resolvem dps, valeu

Comment: boa, funcionou!